# Specflow Playwright - Cant get to the launch the browser at all. What am i missing?

Tags: c#, playwright, specflow

Here's the driver class
[

```
Binding]
public class Driver : IDisposable
{
 private readonly Task<IPage> page;  //similar to driver declaration
 private IBrowser? browser;

 public Driver()
  {
    page = InitializePlaywright();
  }

  public IPage Page => page.Result;    
  private async Task<IPage> InitializePlaywright()
  {
    var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
    {
      Headless = false,
      Timeout = 30000
    });     
    var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
    var page =  await context.NewPageAsync();
    return page;
  }
  public void Dispose()  
  {
    browser?.CloseAsync();
  }
}
```

---

Here's the stepdef:

```
[Binding]
internal class HomeSteps
{
  private readonly Driver driver;
  private readonly HomePage homePage;

  public HomeSteps(Driver driver)
  {
    this.driver = driver;
    homePage = new HomePage(driver.Page);
  }
  [Given(@"User logs into HomePage (.*)")]
  public async Task GivenUserLogsIntoHomePage(string user)
  {
    await homePage.LoginToHomePage(user);
  }
}
```

Have tried changing the browser to WebKit and Firefox just to ensure its nothing to do with Chromium. When I launch the same code in debug mode, get 'this.Page' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'. Cant seem to get past this.
Note: I have a fully working solution with NUNIT C# but trying specflow.

Comment: Resolved, the issue wasnt with the code. Specflow doesnt seem to work with .net6, resolved when i switched to .netcore 3.1

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I have SpecFlow working with .NET 7, and I'm surprised you couldn't get it working with .NET 6. Are you sure it isn't an issue with the NuGet package versions in your project?